# Limbo (programming language) workspace

Tags: programming-languages, workspace

what is the workspace of Limbo?

In other words, where can i write code in Limbo and exceute it?
(like visual studio for C#,C++,VB and eclipse for Java,PHP )

Limbo is a programming language.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbo_(programming_language)#Hello_world

Thanks.

Comment: IDE is what you want to say, not workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://www.vitanuova.com/inferno/) might help you:

From the link:

Inferno is not only an operating system, it is also a complete development environment, providing all the tools necessary for creating, testing and debugging the applications that run within it.

Acme IDE: includes editor, shell, advanced pattern matching tools & more

Fast Compiler: with full syntax and compile time type checking

Graphical Debugger: with full stack trace for currently executing threads

Powerful Shell: with sophisticated scripting capabilities
UNIX like commands: including bind, grep, gzip, mount, ps, tar, yacc...

Comment: There isn't a nicer environment for that language?

Comment: In theory, you could use both Visual Studio and Eclipse to write any language code, because both of them are language-neutral, but it would comprise of a lot of effort to do that as far as I'm aware.

Comment: ok. I've tried installing inferno on my ubuntu but i have this problum.

./makemk.sh
./makemk.sh: 33: ./mkconfig: cannot open /usr/lib/inferno/mkfiles/mkfile-Linux-: No such file
;;;

what should i do?
i changed the varibles in the mkconfig file